# Grouping similar values

Tags: python

I have a list of list

```
list = [[390, 2645, 760, 2736], [395, 2848, 703, 2950], [399, 2747, 767, 2843], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [2055, 2728, 2348, 2831], [2059, 2638, 2351, 2725], [2062, 2840, 2360, 2927], [2065, 2933, 2203, 3033]]
```

I want to make a sub-list where the difference between first values are not greater that 200 example in other sense we can say i want to groupby values whose difference is not greater than 20

like example 399 - 395 < 200 goes in same list list1
1083 - 399 > 200 goes in the different list list2
similarly for other values

```
desired_list = [[[390, 2645, 760, 2736], [395, 2848, 703, 2950], [399, 2747, 767, 2843]], [[1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833]], [[2055, 2728, 2348, 2831], [2059, 2638, 2351, 2725], [2062, 2840, 2360, 2927], [2065, 2933, 2203, 3033]]
```

I have tried using groupby, FOR loops but not getting any success

Comment: Not enough clear what you are seeking!! Please clarify

Comment: Sorry, not only your textual description of the grouping/filtering algorithm is not understandable to me, but also the content of `list` and `desired_list` is completely the same (except that `desired_list` has one opening bracket too much and so is not correct python syntax...) And if you mention an attempt based on for-loops - why don't you post it, so it can perhaps help understand you and perhaps be corrected?

Comment: That said one starting general hint: Do _never_ name variables the same like reserved keywords like `list`, `sum`, `min` or whatever. It will almost always produce problems later.

Comment: What number range should be the basis ? 150-390 < 200, so would you want 150’s sub list in your list? Should we have range of 200 from 400 - [200,600]. It’s a question open to interpretation and should be put on hold.

Comment: I am new in python programming so sorry for the mistakes will make sure not to repeat it

Comment: yes anything more than 200 should be in a different list @cph_sto

Comment: No no, that’s fine that you are a beginner in Python. Just explain the problem at hand clearly, which has nothing to do with python skills 

Comment: 200 what? 850-900 < 200 too. So, should it be in list?

Comment: if difference between two values is less than 200 it should be in a same list and if the difference greater that 200 it should be in a different list. If you look at the ans given by @Partho63 that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list1 = [[390, 2645, 760, 2736], [395, 2848, 703, 2950], [399, 2747, 767, 2843], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [2055, 2728, 2348, 2831], [2059, 2638, 2351, 2725], [2062, 2840, 2360, 2927], [2065, 2933, 2203, 3033]]
list2 = [[]]
counter = 0
list2[counter].append(list1[0])
length1 = len(list1)
for i in range(1, length1):
    if (list1[i][0] - list1[i-1][0]) < 200:
        list2[counter].append(list1[i])
    else:
        list2.append([])
        counter += 1
        list2[counter].append(list1[i])

print(list2)
```

Comment: there are two major issues, the measure is not symmetric (use absolute value) and the list is somehow sorted and not very continues...

Comment: list is indeed sorted by the first value of every list in ascending order @JirkaB. The measurement is currently static I will change it dynamic value but i think the logic is correct and is  what i needed

Comment: ok then it should be written that the list is sored or add a line with ordering `list1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[0])` otherwise `random.shuffle(list1)` breaks it :)

Answer (score 2):

assuming the original list is ordered

```
from functools import reduce

def calcList(s,i):
    if (i[0]-s[-1][-1][0] ) < 200:
        return s[:-1]+[s[-1]+[i]]
    else:
        return s[:-1]+[s[-1]]+[[i]]


res=reduce(lambda s,i: calcList(s,i) ,lst[1:],[[lst[0]]])


>>>res
[[[390, 2645, 760, 2736], [395, 2848, 703, 2950], [399, 2747, 767, 2843]], [[1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833]], [[2055, 2728, 2348, 2831], [2059, 2638, 2351, 2725], [2062, 2840, 2360, 2927], [2065, 2933, 2203, 3033]]]
```

Comment: there are two major issues, the measure is not symmetric (use absolute value) and the list is somehow sorted and not very continues...

Comment: then use absolute value  and I don't understand the second part of your comment

Comment: try to shuffle the list `random.shuffle(list1)` and you will see that each run you get different results

Comment: indeed that's why I wrote "assuming the original list is ordered" if it isn't then the asker should order it by the first item first

Comment: or you can edit your code by adding `list1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[0])`

Answer (score 2):

using `numpy` you can simply compute distances for from each element to the other one and use "group" selection which will be added to the new list if it is not already there...

```
import numpy as np

list1 = np.array([[390, 2645, 760, 2736], [395, 2848, 703, 2950], [399, 2747, 767, 2843], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [2055, 2728, 2348, 2831], [2059, 2638, 2351, 2725], [2062, 2840, 2360, 2927], [2065, 2933, 2203, 3033]])
list2 = []

for i, ref in enumerate(list1):
    close = np.abs(list1[:, 0] - ref[0]) < 200
    if np.sum(close) > 0 and list1[close].tolist() not in list2:
        list2.append(list1[close].tolist())

print ([len(l) for l in list2]) 
# [3, 6, 4]
print (list2)
# [[[390, 2645, 760, 2736], [395, 2848, 703, 2950], [399, 2747, 767, 2843]], [[1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1083, 2641, 1743, 2732], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1085, 2845, 1697, 2932], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833], [1087, 2737, 1741, 2833]], [[2055, 2728, 2348, 2831], [2059, 2638, 2351, 2725], [2062, 2840, 2360, 2927], [2065, 2933, 2203, 3033]]]
```